# An ideal gas is undergoing an isothermal expansion against a constant external pressure. Which of the following statements is true?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-laws

> An ideal gas is undergoing an isothermal expansion against a constant external pressure. Which of the following statements is true?
>
> 1) This process is reversible.
>
> **2) This process is irreversible.**
>
> 3) This process is exothermic.
>
> 4) The system pressure is always in equilibrium with the external pressure.
>
> 5) The information given is insufficient to describe this process.

([source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpMwy.png))

I don't get how the answer can be 2, I thought it would be 5. Since it's expansion, $\Delta S$ of the system must be > 0. Now since it's an expansion, work must be < 0. If work is less than 0, q > 0 due to the process being isothermal. So that means $\Delta S$ of the surroundings < 0 since it is -q/T. That means $\Delta S$ of the universe could be > 0, < 0 (non spontaneous) and = 0 depending on the magnitude of $\Delta S$ of the system and surroundings. As a result, I choose 5 since we don't know the magnitudes of both $\Delta S$.

Why would it be 2?

Answer (score 2):

If the gas is ideal, for an isothermal expansion

$$p=\frac{nRT}{V}=\frac{\textrm{constant}}{V}$$

As the volume of the system changes, so must the pressure.

Now a condition of reversibility is mechanical balance between the system and surroundings, that is, $p=p_{\textrm{ext}}$. However, if a process is performed at constant external pressure *and* temperature, then as shown above the condition of mechanical balance cannot be satisfied, since $p$ will change during the expansion whereas $p_{\textrm{ext}}$ is constant. Therefore the process must be *irreversible*.

Answer (score 2):

If the temperature and pressure are constant, then the change in entropy of the system is $$\Delta S_{syst}=nR\ln{(V_2/V_1)}$$For constant temperature, the change in internal energy is zero, so the heat transfer from the surroundings is $$Q=P_{ext}(V_2-V_1)=\frac{nRT}{V_2}(V_2-V_1)=nRT\left(1-\frac{V_1}{V_2}\right)$$It then follows that the change in entropy of the surroundings is $$\Delta S_{surr}=-\frac{Q}{T}=-nR\left(1-\frac{V_1}{V_2}\right)$$So the total entropy change of the system and surroundings in this process is:
$$\Delta S=-nR\left[\ln{(V_1/V_2)}+\left(1-\frac{V_1}{V_2}\right)\right]$$
This entropy change is positive for all non-unity values of the volume ratio.  The process is therefore irreversible.